# Output a relational symbol on LaTeX (precedes under relation, ⊰)

Tags: relation-symbols

I'm trying to output this character on LaTeX: ⊰ ([click here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22b0/index.htm) if you can't see it)

The more I search and read the more confused I am. At this point I am clueless.

Supposedly the command is `\prurel`, but I found no package related to that macro. The `\mathrel` command is related, but I don't know how, I didn't find a package for that macro either. `\UnicodeMathSymbol{"022B0}` is related somehow, I couldn't figure which way yet. `unicode-math.tex` is related to all these things, but I could not find that file in my installation.

I simply hope it is possible to add this without collateral damages (for instance converting all the other symbols to unicode or anything like that).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an expert at this subject, but after some experimentation and detective work, I've found the following:

- Your guesses about `\UnicodeMathSymbol{"022B0}`, `\prurel` and `\mathrel` seems to be based on the content of the file `[...]texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex`, which contains the following line:

  ```
  \UnicodeMathSymbol{"022B0}{\prurel}{\mathrel}{element precedes under relation}%
  ```
- That file is part of the package `unicode-math`.
- According with [the documentation of that package](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/blob/master/README.markdown):

  > A simple beginning is:
  >
  > ```
  > \usepackage{unicode-math}
  > \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
  > ```

So I tried the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
$a\prurel b$, $c ⊰ d$
\end{document}
```

which had to be compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex` (because it uses `.otf` fonts, only supported with those engines), and produced:

[image: Result]

The conclusion is then that the macro in question (`\prurel`) is simply a way to get the symbol from an appropiate math font which contains it, which in this case is `xits-math.otf` (but the documentation of `unicode-math` lists other compatible fonts), and it will not work if you don't have an appropiate font.

In addition, since apparently that symbol is implemented only in `otf` fonts, you would require `xelatex` or `luatex` to compile your document. I don't know if this qualifies as "collateral damages" :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect. I could have been fighting with pdfTeX for ever. Also my installation seems not to be able to find unicode-math, so I'm going to spend a while with that. Thanks to you now I know what's the goal.

Comment: @Trylks I tried it under texlive 2012 and worked out of the box.

Comment: The problem was that my Texniccenter version was terribly outdated, the new one includes LuaLaTex and XeLaTex. Now everything works out of the box. That was faster than I expected :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is `\prec` and also has a counterpart called `\succ`. Both are math-symbols and must be written within math mode.

Comment: It's hard to see the difference, but that's a different symbol, you can compare [≺](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/227a/index.htm) and [⊰](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22b0/index.htm)

Comment: this may be a different symbol.  unicode has "precedes" at U+227A, while "precedes under relation" (with the ends distinctly recurved) at U+22B0.  (they are cross-referenced in the [unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf).)  `\prurel` is almost certainly in the xits fonts (that's the name assigned during the stix project).  the counterpart (U+22B1) was assigned the name `\scurel`.